# python - Nose not discovering package level tests in Django

Tags: python, django, nose, django-nose

I'm setting up a directory structure for my Django app to separate functional and unit tests. I am using nose as the test runner for my Django project.

At the root of the Django project, I have a folder called "tests" that has this structure:

```
tests
├── __init__.py
├── functional
│   ├── __init__.py
└── unit
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── data.py
    ├── tests.py
```

If I want to run just the unit tests, should I not be able to use the following from the project root:

```
$ nosetests tests.unit

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

As you can see, this doesn't find the tests in the tests.py file.

However, when I run using the directory structure, the tests are found as they should be:

```
$ nosetests tests/unit/
E
# .. Some errors I expected because settings are not initialized when called this way
-----------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

What am I missing? My main issue is that I have a `setup` function in `tests.unit.__init__.py` that should be called for creating the data in the test DB for the upcoming tests.

Thanks

Comment: might you need to include import unit in the first __init__? (just throwing this out there)

Comment: @sihrc don't think so, as I can import the `unit.tests` module from the same directory using the python command-line `python -c 'import tests.unit'`

Comment: Did you try to run nose in verbose mode? try using `-v` and `-vv` to see if they give any hint about the test discovery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all depends on what kind of code is in `tests/unit/__init__.py`

When you say

```
nosetests tests.unit
```

You are pointing to `unit/__init__.py` not the directory `unit/` thus if you had no tests in your `__init__.py` module then nothing would be run. So it is understandable when you say you used the directory path and then your tests started working.

You mention

> What am I missing? My main issue is that I have a setup function in
>   tests.unit.**init**.py that should be called for creating the data in
>   the test DB for the upcoming tests.

It is likely that although you have a setup function in `__init__.py` you may have not ever imported your test functions into `__init__.py`

One quick fix to this would be to add this line in `__init__.py`

```
from tests.unit.tests import *
```

That said it is really not very wise to be putting any code in `__init__.py` at all and if you have code that returns some kind of configuration data I would recommend creating a new library module with functions that will return configuration data to your tests

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My understanding of nose's discovery feature is that it would like for all modules that matched the pattern. So when I point it to tests.unit, that it would find tests.py, and all the test functions inside. But now I added `from .tests import *`, which seems to do the trick. Is there no way to let nose find the tests automatically, instead of importing them manually?

Comment: Yeah just do `nosetests unit/` if you want all the tests found automatically within the directory. As I mentioned, when you say `nosetests tests.unit`, you are telling nose to find all tests in a specific module. If that module has no tests, well then you're out of luck. I don't use much module notation though so I can't speak much more in depth. Maybe look at the source code at https://github.com/nose-devs/nose to find out more